# scrollTop() function infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I know this subject has already been covered but I didn't find something as specific as my problem and the solutions I found didn't work for me (or i couldn't manage to make it work). I basically want to scroll to the top of the next element (a 100% height element) if I scroll down and if I scroll up from that element I would like it to scroll back to the top of the page.

I currently have this :

```
var currDiv = 1;

$(window).scroll(function(event)
{

if (currDiv == 1)
{

    $('html, body').animate({  
        scrollTop:$('div.container').offset().top 
    }, 'slow');  

    currDiv = 2;

}

else if (currDiv == 2)
{

    $('html, body').animate({  
        scrollTop:$('div.albums').offset().top 
    }, 'slow'); 

    currDiv = 1; 

}

});
```

I know it doesn't have the "up" and "down" events yet and that it is wrong on different levels, but it is a first attempt to cycle between them... The problem is that it triggers itself and it keeps cycling back between both elements... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/644eghbw/1/ Here is a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem

Comment: after you set currDiv, put break;  You have to break out of the if.

Comment: Break doesn't work in if functions I think (illegal statement), I tried using return but it didn't work either.

Comment: Can you put a jsfiddle or something with the html also?

Comment: You're animating the scroll position on the scroll event. Animating the scroll position triggers scroll events, thus creating the infinite loop.

Comment: What can I do then to get the desired result ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/644eghbw/1/ here is a jsfiddle of the problem

Comment: @user1898778 What's the desired result?

Comment: Being able to scroll to the the next element when scrolling down, and scrolling to the previous one when scrolling up.

Comment: You need to wait until the user stops scrolling before reacting. There are many questions that answer how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're animating the scroll position on the scroll event. Animating the scroll position triggers scroll events, thus creating the infinite loop.

You need to make sure you don't create another scroll animation while the current one is running. You can use a variable and the animation callback to set it. Here's a [less-than-perfect example](http://jsfiddle.net/stcyhqq7/) that demonstrated the basic concepts.

```
var currDiv = 1;
var scrolling = false;

$(window).scroll(function(event)
{
    if (!scrolling)
    {
        if (currDiv == 1)
        {
            $('html, body').animate({  
                scrollTop:$('.one').offset().top 
            }, 'slow', function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    scrolling = false;
                }, 1000);
            });
            scrolling = true;
            currDiv = 2;
        }
        else if (currDiv == 2)
        {
            $('html, body').animate({  
                scrollTop:$('.two').offset().top 
            }, 'slow', function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    scrolling = false;
                }, 1000);
            });
            scrolling = true;
            currDiv = 1; 
        }
    }
});
```